# Git: squashing material shared between branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch, rebase, squash

I have a git respository that looks a little like this:

```
C0 ---- C1 ---- ... ---- C12 ---- C14 (dev)
                          \
                           \---- C13 (abandoned)
```

'dev' is the main development branch, and 'abandoned' is an experiment that we may want to revisit at some point in the future. 
I would like to squash `C1`... `C12` down into a single commit, to get something like this:

```
C0 ---- C1' ---- C14' (dev)
         \
          \---- C13' (abandoned)
```

I could use interactive rebase on dev to get

```
C0 ---- C1' ---- C14' (dev)
```

then check out `C1'` and cherry-pick `C13` as `C13'`. But is there any easier way of doing this, that would also scale up to handle more complex diagrams with more branches and divergent commits (but some shared history to be squashed) without a lot of manual work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. First, ignore `C13` and just squash down to `C0 - C1' - C14'` with an interactive rebase. But then don't cherry-pick, but rebase `C13`onto `C1'`. `git` should detect that this is basically a no-op, and you will be done. So:

```
git rebase --onto C1_new C12 C13
```

Comment: That worked beautifully in more complex cases. Thank you.